# VBA excel English 2007 cause error msg on excel 2016 french

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2016

I have this Macro used to invert the order of the selected row. 
This Macro run smooth on my english pc with excel 2007 but doesn't work on my french pc with excel 2016. 
When i run it in the french pc, this line  `For j = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) / 2`gets me a error msg

''Compilation error: Syntax error''

```
  Sub FlipRows()
'Updateby20131126
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Arr = WorkRng.Formula
For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    k = UBound(Arr, 2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) / 2
        xTemp = Arr(i, j)
        Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, k)
        Arr(i, k) = xTemp
        k = k - 1
    Next
Next
WorkRng.Formula = Arr
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems like perfectly valid syntax. If you comment it out (and the matching Next) then does the code compile ?

Comment: it compile on the english 2007 version but not on the excel french 2016 version

Comment: I don't think you're answering the question I asked ?

Comment: i'm guessing the ''To'' or the ''Ubound'' might differ from english and french

Comment: sorry williams i dont think i understand the question :S

Comment: Isn't all VBA in English now?  I know there used to be different versions in German/French (?) but not since a long time now...

Comment: Comment out the line which is being flagged as invalid (and the matching `Next` line) and try compiling the project.

Comment: that's what i thought but the only difference between bot files is the 2007 and 2016 or french and english

Comment: Have you tried changing `Arr` to another name? `Arr` seems eerily similar to `Arret` which might be some strange/legacy reserved word?

Comment: Or better still, have you tried using `WorkRng.FormulaLocal`?

Comment: Check the References dialog (go to Tools > References in the VBA editor) and unselect any references marked as missing. Missing references tend to produce very odd syntax errors even in code which makes no use of the reference

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change , to ;

It is a regional setting causing the problem, the reason for the semicolon is to distinguish from the decimal separator that in many countries is comma instead of dot.

Another option is to change the separators in your Excel version (, . and ;)